# MPI program running within a Singularity container on a cluster

Tags: mpi, singularity-container

I am trying to run an MPI application through a singularity container on a cluster and testing first a simple program but I get into trouble.

Here is the test program:

```
program hello
include 'mpif.h'
integer rank, size, ierror, tag, status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)
   
   call MPI_INIT(ierror)
   call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, size, ierror)
   call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierror)
   print*, 'node', rank, ': Hello world'
   call MPI_FINALIZE(ierror)

end
```

I get the following Singularity recipe from https://sylabs.io/guides/3.5/user-guide/mpi.html . I  produce the sif container locally and than move it to the cluster:

```
Bootstrap: docker
From: ubuntu:latest

%environment
    export OMPI_DIR=/opt/ompi
    export SINGULARITY_OMPI_DIR=$OMPI_DIR
    export SINGULARITYENV_APPEND_PATH=$OMPI_DIR/bin
    export SINGULAIRTYENV_APPEND_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$OMPI_DIR/lib

%post
    echo "Installing required packages..."
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget git bash gcc gfortran g++ make file

    echo "Installing Open MPI"
    export OMPI_DIR=/opt/ompi
    export OMPI_VERSION=4.0.1
    export OMPI_URL="https://download.open-mpi.org/release/open-mpi/v4.0/openmpi-$OMPI_VERSION.tar.bz2"
    mkdir -p /tmp/ompi
    mkdir -p /opt
    # Download
    cd /tmp/ompi && wget -O openmpi-$OMPI_VERSION.tar.bz2 $OMPI_URL && tar -xjf openmpi-$OMPI_VERSION.tar.bz2
    # Compile and install
    cd /tmp/ompi/openmpi-$OMPI_VERSION && ./configure --prefix=$OMPI_DIR && make install
```

I load than the same openmpi environment in the cluster in the jobfile :

```
module load OpenMPI/4.0.1-GCC-8.3.0
singularity exec mpicont.sif bash script
mpirun -np 4 singularity exec mpicont.sif ./here/hello
```

where the first singularity call to script compiles the file:

```
export PATH=$OMPI_DIR/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$OMPI_DIR/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export MANPATH=$OMPI_DIR/share/man:$MANPATH

mpif90 -o hello hello.f90
```

What I find is that the first call works very well and the executable `hello` is produced, but the `mpirun` command fails with the following error:

```
anode239:04778] PMIX ERROR: ERROR in file gds_ds12_lock_pthread.c at line 165
[anode239:04778] PMIX ERROR: NOT-FOUND in file gds_ds12_lock_pthread.c at line 199
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
A call to mkdir was unable to create the desired directory:

  Directory: /scratch
  Error:     Read-only file system

Please check to ensure you have adequate permissions to perform
the desired operation.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[anode239:04778] [[11585,1],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Error in file util/session_dir.c at line 107
[anode239:04778] [[11585,1],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Error in file util/session_dir.c at line 346
[anode239:04778] [[11585,1],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Error in file base/ess_base_std_app.c at line 141
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
It looks like orte_init failed for some reason; your parallel process is
likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
fail during orte_init; some of which are due to configuration or
environment problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure;
here's some additional information (which may only be relevant to an
Open MPI developer):

  orte_session_dir failed
  --> Returned value Error (-1) instead of ORTE_SUCCESS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[anode239:04778] [[11585,1],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Error in file ess_pmi_module.c at line 416
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
It looks like orte_init failed for some reason; your parallel process is
likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
fail during orte_init; some of which are due to configuration or
environment problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure;
here's some additional information (which may only be relevant to an
Open MPI developer):

  orte_ess_init failed
  --> Returned value Error (-1) instead of ORTE_SUCCESS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What can be the source of the error and how to fix it ?

Comment: Be aware that using `use mpi` instead of including `mpif.h` can reveal many sorts of errors although the code here is likely not the issue.

Comment: Indeed I do not think that the sample code can be an issue...

Comment: Is `/scratch` bound to a directory where you write/create directory permission?

Comment: Probably not. I do not know why and who is writing to /scratch though ...

Comment: Suggestions to check ?

Comment: Your `$TMPDIR` likely point to `/scratch`. You basically need to tell singularity that `/scratch` is not a directory of the container but the host at build time.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet if I enter the container /scratch does not exist and echo $TMPDIR shows this variable to be empty

Comment: I am trying to create /scratch in the container when building the .sif file, just as a trial...

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet after creating the /scratch directory in my container, the error message changed  from  "Directory: /scratch" to "Directory: /scratch/local", and now complains about not being able to create a folder there... Is this useful information ?

Comment: I suspect `/scratch/...` is coming from the environment of the `mpirun` command or Open MPI or PMIx configuration. This (sub)directory should be writable in your container (just like it exists and is writable on your host) and you likely want to tell your container `/scratch/...` should be the same in both your host and the container.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the project looks like this:

```
├── build.sh
├── hello.f90
└── mpicont.def
```

First create the `.sif` image file.

```
sudo singularity build mpicont.sif mpicont.def
```

This is the script for building the executable using Singularity.

`build.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

export PATH=$OMPI_DIR/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$OMPI_DIR/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export MANPATH=$OMPI_DIR/share/man:$MANPATH

mpif90 -o hello hello.f90
```

Create `hello` executable.

```
singularity exec mpicont.sif bash build.sh
```

The project should now look like this:

```
├── build.sh
├── hello
├── hello.f90
├── mpicont.def
└── mpicont.sif
```

Finally run it.

```
mpirun -np 4 singularity exec mpicont.sif ./hello
```

```
 node           2 : Hello world
 node           3 : Hello world
 node           0 : Hello world
 node           1 : Hello world
```

So that works fine. But there is nothing in the example code that tries to create a directory. The error message specifically mentions that you are denied permission to run `mkdir` on a directory under `/scratch`. Can you please share the code that's trying to do that? Because based on the information provided in the question right now this should all work.

[Gilles Gouaillardet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8062491/gilles-gouaillardet) suggested that the `TMPDIR` environment variable might be at fault. Let's test that hypothesis.

```
export TMPDIR=/scratch
mpirun -np 4 singularity exec mpicont.sif ./hello
```

[image]

Excellent!

So there seem to be (at least) two potential fixes:

1. Unset the `TMPDIR` environment variable. This should be easy to accomplish without elevated permissions. Another option would be to point it to a directory where you do have permission.
2. Create the `/scratch` directory and ensure that you have access to it. This will likely require elevated permissions.

Comment: `/scratch` is likely referenced by `$TMPDIR` on the host, so `singularity exec --bind /scratch mpicont.sif ./hello` could do the trick.